# implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1") not working in kotlin for Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am new to Coding for kotlin an want to convert my old project from java to kotlin and in this project i'd used firebase database ui for chatting and added below the dependency in build.gradle.kts(:app) file.

Hence I am trying to implement the below support dependency and getting error in kotlin file please give me solution if have any?

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.8.1")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:22.4.0")
implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.2.0")
```

//    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.3.0")
implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1")
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.2")
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2")

[image]

What is the solution of this dependency if i want to convert my old project in kotlin?

Comment: Please provide some more details

Comment: Have you tried to use the latest `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'`?

Comment: Yes, i had tried implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'  but not getting succeed.